# Function not Printing two separate print statements

Tags: python, function, printing, terminal, command-line-interface

I am new to personal projects and am working on a library book management system through the python terminal.

I'm running into an issue that has had been stuck for a while.

I'm trying to get my code to print out into the console

------ Main Menu ------

1. All Books
2. Check In
3. Check Out
4. Look Up

But instead it just gives me over and over again just "Choose Option". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've tried iterating a bunch of times over but I can't find the resolution.

**Source Code:**
[image: Source Code]

**Terminal Output:**
[image: Terminal Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future try pasting your code directly into your question rather than as an image.

Regardless, try moving the line starting with `option` i.e.:

```
option = input("Choose options: ")
```

into inside the `mainMenu`
function (`main_menu` in the attempted reconstruction of your attempt below):

```
#
#
# Print menu
# Menu will include a list if menu options
# Create a main menu function that will control the main menu
# Then call functions as they are requested by the user
# Will require a dictionary using id's as the key and book info as values
#
#

import pprint
import os

# Books in the System
books = [
    {"ID": 100001, "title": "Meditations", "author": "Marcus Aurelius", "year": 180},
    {"ID": 100002, "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird", "author": "Harper Lee", "year": 1960},
    {"ID": 100003, "title": "The Great Gatsby", "author": "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "year": 1925},
    {"ID": 100004, "title": "Don Quixote", "author": "Miguel de Cervantes", "year": 1615},
    {"ID": 100005, "title": "The Little Prince", "author": "Antoine de Saint-Exupery", "year": 180}
]

menu = " ------ Main Menu ------ \n\n 1. All Books \n 2. Check In \n 3. Check Out \n 4. Look Up \n"


def menu1():
    pprint.pprint(books)
    option1 = input("Type 0 to go back: ")
    if option1 == "0":
        os.system("clear")
        return main_menu()


def main_menu():
    print(menu)
    option = input("Choose option: ")
    if option == "1":
        os.system("clear")
        return menu1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
 ------ Main Menu ------ 

 1. All Books 
 2. Check In 
 3. Check Out 
 4. Look Up 

Choose option: 1
[{'ID': 100001,
  'author': 'Marcus Aurelius',
  'title': 'Meditations',
  'year': 180},
 {'ID': 100002,
  'author': 'Harper Lee',
  'title': 'To Kill a Mockingbird',
  'year': 1960},
 {'ID': 100003,
  'author': 'F. Scott Fitzgerald',
  'title': 'The Great Gatsby',
  'year': 1925},
 {'ID': 100004,
  'author': 'Miguel de Cervantes',
  'title': 'Don Quixote',
  'year': 1615},
 {'ID': 100005,
  'author': 'Antoine de Saint-Exupery',
  'title': 'The Little Prince',
  'year': 180}]
```

Comment: I tried doing it your way, but I'm still just outputting "Choose Option: " into my terminal. I'm running this on the latest Python and the code seems fine.

Comment: `print(menu)` is above the line `option = input("Choose option: ")`? I don't see how that is possible?

Comment: I literally copied your code and I'm getting the same thing, I don't see how its possible either, I'm trying to break it down and it doesn't make sense to me. Do you have any recommendations in how to build this?

Comment: Maybe try it out on https://repl.it Seems to work on there. Or watch a youtube video for setting up python in some other way e.g. you could download PyCharm.